# Permission.locationAlways.isGranted always returns false ios

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions

I am using the permission_handler package in flutter to access permissions of the underlying device that my app would run on.

My problem, however, is that the Permission.locationAlways.isGranted always returns false, even when I have changed the permission to "always allow" in the app settings.

Here's the function that checks the phone's permission using the permission_handler package:

```
void _checkLocationPermission() async {
  bool isGranted = await Permission.locationAlways.isGranted;
  print("isGranted -- $isGranted");
  if (_locationPermissionGranted != isGranted) {
    setState(() {
      _locationPermissionGranted = isGranted;
    });
  }
}
```

This function is called in the initState() method of the screen. I would appreciate any guidance to solve this; it seems pretty simple and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you installed the package properly on ios. Modify the podfile appropriately as explained here: [here](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). Also, this video may help, in case you're struggling with the instructions in the previous link: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ral4D3X9fE)

Comment: Thank you so much! The installation instructions on pub.dev weren't clear but the video helped a lot!